# Ember select view inside of an each not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

So I've got an Ember select view inside of an `each` that changes the context. And I am assuming that's why I  cannot get access to the controller property.

This is the code

```
{{#each stuff}}
    {{view Ember.Select class="form-control" content=../all_types value=type}}
{{/each}}


//In my controller 
//I have this variable
all_types: ['stuff', 'more stuff', 'even more stuff']
```

So I've tried `all_types` and `../all_types` which seems to be the way to refer to the parent context. Even so, it's not working.

I do want to say that other `Ember select views` are working in the same way that I am trying with this one, the only difference is that they are outside of the each loop. Which is why I assume that the each is causing the issue.

Comment: What is it telling you in the console?

Comment: Can you show the surrounding code? I specifically want to see your controller and why you need the each helper in context

Comment: My controller has a lot of code that can't really be shown. The `stuff` variable is from the model that I am iterating over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`../` changes the context of the entire helper, not just a property, it's easier to think about it like this

```
{{view Ember.Select class="form-control" ../ content=all_types value=type}}
```

You'll need to rescope or change your each, assuming `all_types` was in the parent scope

```
{{#each item in stuff}}
    {{view Ember.Select class="form-control" content=all_types value=item.type}}
{{/each}}
```